# Detect when IMG element has loaded in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I am using `Angular 2` and I need to detect if an image has loaded in an image tag.

Is there an event for that?

Something like this :

```
<img [src]="imagesource" [loaded]="dosomething()">
```

Answer (score 172, accepted):

```
<img [src]="imagesource" (load)="dosomething()">
```

Comment: Hi, do you know why `Observable.fromEvent(elementReference, 'load')` does not work the same way? Also, any hint on why `dosomething()` gets called more than once each time `src` changes? Thanks

Comment: I think that `dosomething()` is called twice is a Chrome issue. I investigated and commented on a similar question but don't remember details.

Comment: Ok thanks, and any experience on `Observable.fromEvent(imgElementReference, 'load')` vs `<img (load)="...">`?

Comment: I never tried `Observable.fromEvent(elementReference, 'load')`. How does it not work the same way?

Comment: Oh ok no problem them, it was just curiosity, I ended up using the method you suggested in the answer. I was just wondering why the jQuery method `.on('load')` seems to work while the Observable equivalent (I suppose) does not (in the sense that the Observables' subscription is never triggered).

Comment: Perhaps a problem with `elementReference`? How do you get it? Perhaps you need `elementReference.nativeElement`.

Comment: Was just a guess. Sorry, no idea.

Comment: No problem at all, thanks a lot anyway for your time!

Comment: Hello, what about if there are `srcset` attributes and this is a responsive image, will that also work?

Comment: Sure, why not? `src` and `load` in my code are not Angular specific. These are a property and an event from the `<img>` element.

Comment: Hi guys, (load) event doesn't fire with me, while (error) event fires!, any ideas

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks, I got the cause, the image was within *ngIf whose condition was false.  Sorry for bothering.

Comment: is there any other way to listen changes on src like i could subscribe to this? I have element in ts file.

Comment: You can always create an observable using `Observable.fromEvent`, otherwise, no, that's a DOM event unrelated to Angular. My code above just shows how to listen to DOM events using Angular binding syntax.

Answer (score 10):

Extending the first answer to examine the image that just loaded.

```
    <img [src]="imagesource" (load)="onImageLoad($event)">

      onImageLoad(evt) {
        if (evt && evt.target) {
          const width = evt.target.naturalWidth;
          const height = evt.target.naturalHeight;
          const portrait = height > width ? true : false;
          console.log(width, height, 'portrait: ', portrait);
        }
      }
```

However, I saw that chrome sends the event twice, with different sizes! I was able to detect the correct size from the event where evt.scrElement.x and y was zero. But this might not always be the case and I'm not sure why there are two events?

```
    onImageLoad(evt) {
        if (evt && evt.target) {
          const x = evt.srcElement.x;
          const y = evt.srcElement.y;
          if ((x === 0 ) && (y === 0)) {
            const width = evt.srcElement.width;
            const height = evt.srcElement.height;
            portrait = height > width ? true : false;
            console.log('Loaded: ', width, height, 'portrait: ', portrait);
          }
        }
     }
```

Comment: What is the difference between the load and and onload listeners?

Comment: Good question. I am not sure but I think that onload is the native html event, and load is the Angular template equivalent. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301624/angular-img-loading-directive.

Comment: @Ben, in Angular the events you attach in the html tag are the same without `on`, e.g. (click) vs onclick, (keydown) vs onkeydown, etc. -see that in javascript not enclosed by `(` `)`. When you use `fromEvent` rxjs operator, `HostListener` or `addEventListener` you always use the "not on" way. (the event name are click, keydown, load...)