# Angular 2 - Is there an event, when UI binding is finished

Tags: angular

If I change the value of a bounded object in my component, angular automatically updates the value on the UI. This update-process takes some milliseconds (depend on the device). Is there an event when the UI-update-process finished?

At the moment I use following code:

```
// refresh binding
boundedItem = newValue;

// wait 100 milliseconds and the open the browsers print view 
setTimeout(() => {
    // open browser print view
}, 100);
```

On slow devices (smartphones) the process could be take more than 100 milliseconds, so the code is not really clean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just invoke change detection explicitely, then you know the view is updated before further code is executed:

```ts
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef)  {}

someMethod() {
  boundedItem = newValue;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  // view update is completed here
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: this works for data only but how can i  do this for data and images that are loaded

Comment: @cpiock https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257687/detect-when-image-has-loaded-in-img-tag/39257902#39257902

Comment: used this to have my function wait until a new array loaded into a controller variable before scrolling down to a given position in the list. works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Life-cycle hook:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){

}
```