# Typescript - Check if image src has been fetched and call a function

Tags: angular, image, function, typescript, fetch

I have the following element on my page:

```
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2c/9d/07/2c9d0704ae49dfde914e2b477bf9279c--stick-figure-profile-pictures.jpg" />
```

How can I check when the src has been successfully fetched and call a function after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer,Let try this once,

html file,

```
<img [src]="imagesource" (load)="doSomething()">
<!--(or)-->
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2c/9d/07/2c9d0704ae49dfde914e2b477bf9279c--stick-figure-profile-pictures.jpg" (load)="doSomething()">
```

Typescript file,

```
imagesource="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2c/9d/07/2c9d0704ae49dfde914e2b477bf9279c--stick-figure-profile-pictures.jpg";

doSomething(){
   console.log("Loaded");
   //do your stuff
}
```

For more reference visit here

[Detect when image has loaded in img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257687/detect-when-image-has-loaded-in-img-tag)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2c/9d/07/2c9d0704ae49dfde914e2b477bf9279c--stick-figure-profile-pictures.jpg" (load)="myFunction()"/>
```

Note the `(load)="myFunction()"` at the end (the way the content scrolls when it is code is slightly funky).