# How to know when an image has been fully loaded in angular?

Tags: angular, image

How could I do to know when an image has been fully loaded and then show it? Let me explain: I'm showing an image in the following way:

```html
<img src = "www.domain.com">
```

but there are times it takes to load and I want to show it only when it is ready to show (100% loaded), as you might know when Is 100% loaded that image? and I would like to show a loading spinner while the loading of that image is complete, I am using angular 7.

Comment: You may want to look at the `(load)` event

Comment: @yurzui onload ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect when image has loaded in img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257687/detect-when-image-has-loaded-in-img-tag)

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference in how you would check it in Angular or in js.

You need to check for `img.complete` flag or wait for `image.onLoad` event to be fired.

Angular directives allow us to handle such behaviors of element, so let's create a directive:

```js
import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'img[loaded]'
})
export class LoadedDirective {

  @Output() loaded = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('load')
  onLoad() {
    this.loaded.emit();
  }

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLImageElement>) {
    if (this.elRef.nativeElement.complete) {
      this.loaded.emit();
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can catch when an image has been loaded by simple code:

```html
<img src="..." alt="" (loaded)="do whatever you want here">
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/EaDtRWgwgvfGG7potyf0)**

Comment: There is no "loaded" event and that is why you have to create a directive? Excuse me, I'm starting with angular.

Comment: There's `load` event but you have to check `complete` property because there can be a case when image is being loaded from cache so `(load)` event will never be fired

Comment: If you're sure that there is no caching for image then simply use `(load)="do smth"` instead of creating directive and using `(loaded)="..."`

Comment: ok I understand. Will there be a tutorial or a page where you can guide me and thus understand what you have done? since I do not understand the code because I'm just starting with angular. I did not want to copy and paste without understanding it.

Comment: Firstly, this code does almost the same as js implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/how-to-create-a-javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded with only one difference: I don't check for errors

Comment: Any directive can define Output event and can use HostListener https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener to handle any native events such as click, mousemove, load etc

Comment: We can inject ElementRef in any directive and will be refer to the host element https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef