# How to get Image width / height if the image is too big in Angular?

Tags: angular

When I try to log image width in `ngAfterViewInit` method

I get `width = 0` Since the image is too Big

How can I properly see the image width without using a `setTimeout()`

Here is the [code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pfjyrk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

PS. I tried the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280049/how-to-create-a-javascript-callback-for-knowing-when-an-image-is-loaded/280087#280087) but was unsuccessful

This is what i see

[image]

Comment: In your demo it logs width = 10315

Comment: @LukasS i added a screen shot, maybe your internet is very fast thats why you see it properly

Comment: @LukasS dota is right ...on *first* load it is 0.

Comment: @AndrewAllen maybe on second load it is cached i have cached turned off

Comment: I think this is way to go...https://stackoverflow.com/a/39257902/4711754

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per answer here [Detect when image has loaded in img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257687) hook into load event

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <img #hdImage
  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Pizigani_1367_Chart_10MB.jpg"
  (load)="dosomething(hdImage.width)">
  `,
  styles: [``]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @ViewChild('hdImage', { static: false }) HdImage: ElementRef;
  img: HTMLImageElement;

  dosomething(width: number) {
    console.log('[dosomething] width', width);
  }

}
```

@AlexandrMihalciuc answer is better as it is better to pass the width directly so I've stolen it to improve this now accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Subscrive to load event of the img tag:

```
 <img #hdImage      src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Pizigani_1367_Chart_10MB.jpg" (load)="loaded(hdImage.width)">
```

Comment: Can you please show me how ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xukke1?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: I mean can I `subscribe` (RxJs)  to this method ?

Comment: (load)="loaded(hdImage.width)" calls the component function, and in this function you are free to do what you need, so you can add next value to a earlier created subject.