# Detect resources loading in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an issue with a directive that I created in Angular.
In this directive, I want to execute some code after the window.onload event to be sure that all the page resources have been loaded (because I want to know the page top offset of some elements in the directive and if the images are not loaded, this offset is not correct)

If I refresh the page, it works because of the window.onload event is fired but when using the angular navigation to reach my component, this event is not fired anymore.
I tried to use the lifecycle of angular like AfterViewInit but most of the time the AfterViewInit method is executed before the images are loaded.

**UPDATE**
This is the code of my directive :

```
export class ParallaxDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() coef = 1;

    start = 0;
    path = 0;
    initialTranslate = 0;
    intersectObserver: IntersectionObserver;
    inView: boolean;

    constructor(
      private element: ElementRef
    ) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      window.addEventListener('load', () => this.initParallax());
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.intersectObserver.unobserve(this.element.nativeElement);
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', () =>this.setTransform());
    }

    initParallax(): void {
      this.intersectObserver = new IntersectionObserver(this.intersect.bind(this));
      this.intersectObserver.observe(this.element.nativeElement);

      const initialY = new DOMMatrixReadOnly(window.getComputedStyle(this.element.nativeElement).getPropertyValue('transform')).m42;
      this.start = this.element.nativeElement.offsetTop + initialY;
      this.path = this.element.nativeElement.clientHeight;
      this.initialTranslate = (initialY /
this.element.nativeElement.clientHeight) * 100;
      if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
        this.setTransform(true);
      }
      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => this.setTransform());
  }

  setTransform(force = false): void {
    if (!this.inView && !force) {
      return;
    }
    const offset = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - this.start;
    const t = (offset * 10) / this.path;
    const i = t * this.coef + this.initialTranslate;
    this.element.nativeElement.style.setProperty('transform', `translate3d(0, ${i}%, 0)`);
  }

  intersect(entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[], observer: IntersectionObserver): void {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      this.inView = entry.isIntersecting || entry.intersectionRatio > 0;
    });
  }

}
```

As you can see, I need to retrieve some offsets and dom elements height. The problem is that these offsets and heights are not the same after resources in the page (like images) are completely loaded that's why I need to have an event like window.onload to be sure that everything is loaded. And I didn't find any Angular lifecycle that should be triggered after resources load.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Angular routing does not trigger window events. You have to use the life cycle methods as you are using. Please give more detail as to what you're trying and how it fails.

Comment: In `ngOnInit` don't subscribe to `load` because it will never fire. Just do your init call directly.

Comment: But in the ngOnInit, the resources are not loaded and the value of this.element.nativeElement.clientHeight is therefore not correct

Comment: You're right, use `AfterViewInit`

Comment: Unfortunately AfterViewInit is triggered before the resources load too... So I still don't have the good value for the clientHeight of my element

Comment: Use `@HostListener('resize')` to detect host element size changes

Comment: Yes but all resources are not loaded at once, so the event will be triggered many times..

Comment: You can wait for it to stabilize by piping it through a debounce filter - do you know how to do that using rxjs?

Comment: Yes and what if one of the picture takes too much time to load and therefore is not in the debounce time? it's not enough reliable in this case. Don't we have any equivalent of window.load on angular navigation?

Comment: Debounce simply prevents rapid changes. It will get the event even if it takes a while.

Comment: Yes but as we will have a lot of resize event, if some of them a rapid they will be handled by the debounce, but if one of them is slower and not handled by the debounce, the resize event will be triggered multiple times

Comment: Thats right. Thats the best you can do

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help and your time.
I can't believe there is nothing on angular to catch the resources load event, like window.onload..

Comment: If it exists outside of angular then you can catch it in angular - but the problem is it doesn't exist outside angular either.

Comment: If we have window.onload being able to know if all the resources are loaded we should be able to have it on angular too, no? The problem comes from angular navigation in this case that does not trigger this event

Comment: That is because the resources are created dynamically by angular and therefore AfterViewInit should work. Can you specify exactly what doesn't work with that?

Comment: As I say in my question and in the comment, Afterview init is triggered before the img is really loaded. 
Window.onload is triggered when all the resources of the page are completely loaded

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39257902/235648

Comment: Yes unfortunately this does not help me, because the number of image is dynamic and that doesn't tell me if they are all loaded.
I used document.querySelector('img') in the afterViewInit method to retrieve the imgs, and then count the number of img and the number of img loaded to ensure that they are all loaded, but the querySelector returns me the img of the previous component also...

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11071687/235648

Comment: Can't you tell from your component logic how many images are added to the page? (this is starting to become personal for me :) )

Comment: I have component A with 5 images.
I have component B with 8 images.

If I navigate from A to B, document.images returns 13 images in afterviewInit.
If I refresh only B, document.images returns 8 images in afterviewinit.

Comment: Can't you tell in the component logic how many images are used? And subscribe to their `load` events the angular way? - If you subsribe the angular way (`(load)="..."`) then it will not fire if the component is not active

Comment: Yes I can count all the image I have static in my page, and all the dynamic images count all the loaded image using the angular (load) but I really don't want to hardcode all this values when I update my page or something, but that's a solution.
I find it very strange that retrieving all the images in the afterViewInit method also returns me the images of the previous component after the navigation...

Comment: It's not strange, it's even expected. Angular hides components instead of removing them from the DOM so that when navigating back to them, it can simply bring them back into view without recreating them. - Also, I don't see this as hard coding, since your images are probably used in `*ngFor` so it should be concise

Comment: I believe my answer addresses all your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long long exchange of comments, I finally understood your problem, Romain, and here's what I came up with.

My solution involves adding a directive and a service. The directive will be attached to all `<img>` tags, and will subscribe to their `load` events, and the service will coordinate all the `load` events firing and maintain a running list of images that are still being loaded.

Here's the directive:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'img'
})
export class MyImgDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private imageService: ImageService) {
    imageService.imageLoading(el.nativeElement);
  }

  @HostListener('load')
  onLoad() {
    this.imageService.imageLoadedOrError(this.el.nativeElement);
  }

  @HostListener('error')
  onError() {
    this.imageService.imageLoadedOrError(this.el.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

Here's the service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImageService {
  private _imagesLoading = new Subject<number>();
  private images: Map<HTMLElement, boolean> = new Map();
  private imagesLoading = 0;

  imagesLoading$ = this._imagesLoading.asObservable();

  imageLoading(img: HTMLElement) {
    if (!this.images.has(img) || this.images.get(img)) {
      this.images.set(img, false);
      this.imagesLoading++;
      console.log('images loading', this.imagesLoading);
      this._imagesLoading.next(this.imagesLoading);
    }
  }

  imageLoadedOrError(img: HTMLElement) {
    if (this.images.has(img) && !this.images.get(img)) {
      this.images.set(img, true);
      this.imagesLoading--;
      console.log('images loading', this.imagesLoading);
      this._imagesLoading.next(this.imagesLoading);
    }
  }
}
```

And here's how I would use it in your parallax directive:

```js
  constructor(private imageService: ImageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = imageService.imagesLoading$.pipe(filter(r => r === 0)).subscribe(_ => {
      this.initParallax()
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

How does this work? The image directive gets attached to all images regardless of how deep they are in your component tree, registers the image with the service, and then tracks the loading progress by listening to the `load` event. Every time a new directive is created it means a new image is created, so a counter is incremented, and every time `load` fires, it means an image has finished loading, so the counter is decremented. We emit this counter in an observable, and so we can detect when all images are ready by waiting for the observable to emit the value `0`.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-klfvi6?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**EDIT** Added error handling in case an image points to a broken link

Comment: If you decide to accept my answer, I think you should change the title of the question to "Detect when all images have done loading" or something like that

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and your time. I will accept this as the right answer but I must say that I'm a bit that the resource loading event is not really handled by Angular.

Comment: You wouldn't have managed to do it any other way without a full page reload - don't you agree?

Comment: Yes I agree, that's why I accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use HostListener

```
import { HostListener, Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<h1>{{message}}</h1>`
})
class AppComponent {
  message = "Window not loaded";

  @HostListener('load', ['$event'])
  windowLoadedEvent(event) {
    this.message = "Window loaded";
  }
}
```

Note: It will work only if the component is initialized before window is loaded. Otherwise it will not work

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as you say, it doesn't work if the component is loaded after window.load..